# read large gb file and get error "client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I used the "cat" command to read a large gb log file and an error occurred a few hours later and the process always failed to read

getting error

```
"client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe"
```

i used to read multiple large file this command

```
cat log-202106*.csv | grep -v -e ".rasd.urban.com" -e "10.10.19.16" | awk -F\" '{print $18, $14, $6, $2, $4}' OFS=, | sort -n -T /home/log/Output/all_log | uniq >> output_all.csv
```

how to read without this "client loop error"

Comment: are you running the command on a remote machine via ssh?

Comment: Probably can be done all that with `awk`

Comment: Use `awk` to do the filtering that you're currently doing with `grep`. And of course you don't need the Useless Use Of Cat since both `awk` and `grep` take filenames as arguments.

Comment: Also, some versions of `sort` offer a `-u` option that would do the job of `uniq`.

Comment: @jhnc yes I used this command on a remote machine

Comment: @Shawn without using cat use to read awk file as "awk -F\" '{print $}' log.csv" ?

Comment: @Shawn to filter using regex in awk command without using grep -v -e?

Comment: @jhnc is this SSH client error and It has nothing to do with cat or awk command?

Comment: Try to change the configuration of ssh client for keep alive (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602518/ssh-connection-client-loop-send-disconnect-broken-pipe-or-connection-reset)